# Is there a chance in PL/SQL to get the name of a variable as a string?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to get the name of a variable as a string within Oracle PL/SQL. Do you have any ideas, how to do so? In Oracle*Forms there are useful functions like NAME_IN which is not available in PL/SQL. But I need to do that within native PL/SQL. Thank you very much.

```
PROCEDURE px (pi_foo IN number) IS
begin
  insert into mytable (my_var_name, my_var_value)
               values (magic_function_we_are_searching_for(pi_foo), pi_foo);
end;

PRODEDURE py_calls_px IS
  v_var1 number := 999;
begin
  px(pi_foo => v_var1);
end;
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen if the procedure was called with a literal (e.g. `px(999)`) instead of a variable? Is there a reason you can't just pass in the variable name as a second argument?

Comment: Hi Alex, of course I can pass the variable's name as a second argument. But then I have to write the variable twice (with and without quotation) . In a very powerful and complex trace-to-file mechanism it's twice the write-load for the developer. So I'd like to find out, if there is a way, even if it means to select some structures in V$ views during runtime.

Comment: Hi, what is objective to get the name of variable?

Comment: What variable do you want to report in your example? The only variable I can see is `v_var1` within `py_calls_px`.

Comment: The objective is to write less code. For tracing purposes I have tons of lines like this:


`sysg.gbase.pvn ('pi_email_address');     sysg.gbase.vvc (pi_email_address);     sysg.gbase.log2file;`


I would like to do it in just one call without writing the variable's name twice (first for the content, second for the name).

Comment: So in `px` you want to capture the name of the variable in the calling procedure (`v_var1`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is start point to you.
You should need to learn more about **utl_call_stack.subprogram** and also make decision about access rights to **SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS** (if you need it really).
But it's just details.

```
create or replace procedure my_proc(my_foo in varchar2) is
  PROC_NAME varchar2(50) := utl_call_stack.subprogram(1)(1);
  NAME_IN varchar2(50);
begin
    SELECT
        ARGUMENT_NAME
    INTO
        NAME_IN
    FROM SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS
    where OBJECT_NAME  = PROC_NAME
      and IN_OUT = 'IN';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(NAME_IN || ' = ' || my_foo);
end;

begin
    my_proc('bar');
end;

-- result --
MY_FOO = bar
```

Comment: Dear Alex, thank you so much. This is exactly what solves my problem. Thank you very much! Yours, Gerhard

Comment: Dear Alex, sorry for bothering you with another question. ALL_ARGUMENTS or DBA_ARGUMENTS are keeping all IN/OUT parameters for procedures and functions which are defined at first level within a package. Do you know if there is a way to find out the parameters of functions/procedures wich are defined within a first-level-package-procedure's declaration-section.
```procedure p1  (par1 IN number) is procedure p2 (par2 IN number) is begin null; end p2; begin p2(17); end p1;```

That means, where to find par2 within Oracle's dictionary?

Comment: Only public procedures/functions etc are published in the data dictionary. Also, some of those will have more than one argument.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, thank you very much. The worst case will be, to write a parser for USER_SOURCE to find even parameters in private procedures.